# Need help with a complex SQL query - I think I need a two-stage inner join or something like that?

Tags: sql, mysql

Okay, here's what I'm trying to do. I have a drupal table (term_data) in mysql that lists tags and their ID numbers and a second table, (term_node) that shows the relationship between tags and the data the tags refer to. For example, if node 1 had 3 tags, "A", "B" and "C". term_data might look like this:

```
name tid
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

and term_node might look like this:

```
nid  tid
1    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
3    2
```

In this example, node 1 has been tagged with "A" and "B", node 2 has been tagged with "A" and node 3 has been tagged with "B", and "C".

I need to write a query that, given a tag name, list for me all the OTHER tags that are ever used with that tag. In the above example, searching on "A" should return "A" and "B" because node 1 uses both, searching on "C" should return "B" and "C", and searching on "B" should return "A", "B" and "C".

Any ideas? I got this far:

select distinct n.nid from term_node n INNER join term_data t where n.tid = t.tid and t.name='A';

Which gives me a list of every node that has been tagged with "A" - but I can't figure out the next step.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It seems that node 2 has been tagged with B, not A. Or did I miss something?

Comment: In your example node 3 has only been tagged with "B" and "C"

Comment: Think he just made a mistake when he said *node 3 has been tagged with "A","B" and "C"* since his other paragraphs + the data match.  Should have just been Node 3=B+C

Comment: Rudu is correct - I changed my example and forgot to edit it.

Comment: Still says node 2 has been tagged "A", though as I see that tid = 2 (B) when nid = 2 (node 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select distinct d2.name
from term_data d1
join term_node n1 on d1.tid = n1.tid
join term_node n2 on n1.nid = n2.nid
join term_data d2 on n2.tid = d2.tid
where d1.name = 'A'
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated: Mark pointed out that the query wasn't correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name, t2.name Other 
FROM
   term_data t 
   INNER JOIN term_node n ON t.tid = n.tid
   INNER JOIN term_node n2 ON n2.nid = n.nid
   INNER JOIN term_data t2 ON n2.tid = t2.tid
WHERE
   t.name = 'A'
```

Marks answer should be accepted since he got it right first. Here is a demonstration of a similar query

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/13283/demo-for-need-help-with-a-complex-sql-query

Comment: This will just come up with 'A', 'A' repeated for every time tag A occurs on a Node.

Comment: tag? is that a mysql feature?

Comment: @Mike, no, tag is your table name, and t is an alias

Answer (score 1):

Your description of term_node data and the example do not seem to match but using the example data provided I believe the following query will do what you need.

```
select distinct td.name, td2.name as tagged_name
from term_data td
inner join term_node tn
on tn.tid = td.tid
inner join term_node tn2
on tn2.nid = tn.nid
inner join term_data td2
on td2.tid = tn2.tid
```

The first join looks up the term_node records that match the name, term_node is then joined to itself to find all other tid's for that node, finally the second term_node is joined to term_data to retrieve the names of the tag.

You need to tack on the appropriate where clause to select just the tag you want.

Result set follows for above:-

```
name    tagged_name
A       A
A       B
B       A
B       B
B       C
C       B
C       C
```

Hope this helps

Ray

Comment: you can format your answers into code-format using the `101` button.

Comment: Thanks, it's my first post, please excuse ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I created the schema in my workbench, and here's the query I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM `term_data` WHERE `term_data`.`tid` IN (
    SELECT `term_node`.`tid` from `term_node` WHERE `nid` IN (
        SELECT `nid` FROM `term_node` JOIN `term_data` ON `term_data`.`tid` = `term_node`.`tid` WHERE `term_data`.`name` = 'A'
    )
);
```

Sorry for the structure ;) Here's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `term_data` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `term_node` (
  `term_node_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_node_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This seemed to work as expected, if I understood your question correctly. So one more time, we have some nodes which are tagged. We'd like to select a tag (A), and then select other tags that were used to tag same nodes as tag A.

Cheers.

P.S. Output is the following:

```
tid      name

/* For tag A */
1        A
2        B

/* For tag B */
1        A
2        B
3        C

/* For tag C */
2        B
3        C
```